# Use & (ampersand) in single line bash loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, process

I have been using this command successfully, which changes a variable in a config file and then executes a Python script within a loop:

```
for((i=114;i<=255;i+=1)); do echo $i > numbers.txt; python DoMyScript.py; done
```

As each `DoMyScript.py` instance takes about 30 seconds to run before terminating, I'd like to relegate them to the background while the next one can be spawned.

I have tried what I am familiar with, by adding in an ampersand as below:

```
for((i=114;i<=255;i+=1)); do echo $i > numbers.txt; python DoMyScript.py &; done
```

However, this results in the below error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Drop the `;` after `&`. This is a [syntactic requirement](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet)

```
for((i=114;i<=255;i+=1)); do echo $i > numbers.txt;python DoMyScript.py & done
```

Comment: Damn it, 43 seconds too slow :)

Comment: @MartinvonWittich, a +1 to your answer by way of commiseration ;-)

Comment: While that answers the question, it's probably not what the OP wants as by the time all the python instances have started and initialises they'll all see a `numbers.txt` containing `255`.

Comment: Agreed with @StephaneChazelas, but am not sure what we can really do about it with the information given in the question. A proper solution to that probably needs more context.

Comment: That worked great. OP likes the outcome, the file is changed and then read each time, so each iteration of the script gets a different variable. I did need to add in a 3 second delay just to avoid some race-condition/oddities.

Comment: Here's the bash manual reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman, I would not have thought to search under `lists`, based on my previous usage of `&` limited to just appending it to commands to shush them. Time to bash my head against bash properly!

Answer (score 16):

Given Stephane's comment on [1_CR's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91687/4667), you probably want:

```
for i in {114..255}; do { echo $i > numbers.txt && python DoMyScript.py; } & done
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn. I tried a few variations of your code which I like due to the increased readability, but perhaps due to the extra sleep I needed, it was not working out for me. It would also repeat the last number in the `for` range... Here's what I am happy with at the moment: `for((i=1;i<100;i+=1)); do echo $i > numbers.txt;sleep 3; python DoMyScript.py & done` The main question point of getting the process to execute in the background is solved.

Comment: *of course, I had `<=` in the original question, so the range you supplied was totally suitable based on the info I supplied. Again, thanks for the different approach

Comment: Changing the ``;`` after ``echo $i > numbers.txt`` to `&&` is an improvement.  OTOH, if you can’t write a three-digit number to a file, you should probably abort the whole operation, and if you can write to the file on some iterations but not others, you have a problem that needs to be investigated and resolved. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … But, aside from that, I don’t see how this offers any real improvement.  You still have 112 ``python DoMyScript.py`` processes being spawned milliseconds apart.  Unless `DoMyScript.py` starts *very* quickly, the shell loop will have gone on and written the next value to `numbers.txt` before `DoMyScript.py` has read the value it’s supposed to read.

Answer (score 14):

Lose the `;`:

```
for((i=114;i<=255;i+=1)); do echo $i > numbers.txt;python DoMyScript.py & done
```

Answer (score 6):

As stated by the other answers:

- The problem is the `;` after the `&`.
- Deleting the `;` after the `&` will result in a command
  that will run without shell syntax errors. 
  However, it is unlikely to function correctly,
  because it creates a race condition.

The OP stated that he resolved the race condition by adding a 3 second delay.

Nobody mentioned:

- A 3 second delay might work today. 
  Tomorrow, the computer might be more sluggish, and it could fail again. 
  Next year, the script might be modified to be more time-consuming,
  and it could fail again. 
  The probability of failure goes down if you increase the delay
  by an order of magnitude, by which I mean 30 seconds. 
  Of course this means that the script processes will (probably / presumably)
  be running essentially sequentially, and not concurrently (in parallel),
  thus defeating the purpose of making the processes asynchronous.
- If running multiple instances of the script is a requirement,
  it’s probably best to modify the script to accept the number parameter
  on the command line:

  ```
  for ((i=114;i<=255;i++)); do python DoMyScript.py --number="$i" & done
  ```

  and do away with the file.
- If changing the script is not an option, this solution should work:

  ```
  for i in {114..125}; do ( subdir="dir.$i" && mkdir "$subdir" && cd "$subdir" && 
            echo "$i" > numbers.txt && python ../DoMyScript.py; cd .. && rm -r "$subdir" ) & done
  ```

  This gives each script process a separate `numbers.txt` file,
  by giving it a separate directory to run in. 
  The directory is created and deleted, and the script is run, in a subshell.

  - If `DoMyScript.py` accesses any files other than `numbers.txt`
    by relative pathnames,
    the above command will need to be adjusted to accommodate that.
  - The above was inspired by [glenn jackman’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91684/80216#91713)
    (although I believe that mine will work and his won’t).
  - If command *`B`* depends on the success of command *`A`*,
    then `A && B` is better defensive programming
    than `A; B`. 
    But it’s probably not the ideal way to handle this situation. 
    If `mkdir dir.114` fails, then the next 111 attempts are likely to fail also,
    and you’ll get 112 error messages. 
    It would be better to abort the loop if a fatal error occurs.

    The fact that the action is happening in an asynchronous subshell
    makes this somewhat tricky.

    ```
    for i in {114..125}; do
            { subdir="dir.$i" && mkdir "$subdir" && echo "$i" > "$subdir"/numbers.txt; } || break;
            ( cd "$subdir" && python ../DoMyScript.py; cd .. && rm -r "$subdir" ) & done
    ```

    will cause the loop to abort if a `mkdir`
    or an `echo value > file` command fails.
  - It might be better to work in a directory
    that is ‘‘guaranteed’’ to be writable, like `/tmp`. 
    However, this increases the risk that your command
    will collide (interfere) with some other process.

    - You can mitigate this by adding `$$` to the directory name;
      e.g., `dir.$$.$i` or even `dir.$BASHPID`.
    - This would not eliminate the risk that the `mkdir`
      or the file creation might fail because the filesystem is full.
  - Note that the above code will keep on going
    and remove the temporary directory even if the script fails. 
    You might want to do something else in that situation.

    - Oops. 
      If, for some reason,
      the `mkdir "$subdir"` succeeds but the `cd "$subdir"` fails,

      this will go ahead and do `cd .. && rm -r "$subdir"`. 
      If there is a directory with a name like `dir.114` in your parent directory
      (i.e., parallel to your current directory), it will be removed. 
      I believe that you can (at least somewhat) fix this
      by changing the last line to

      ```
      ( cd "$subdir" && { python ../DoMyScript.py; cd ..; } && rm -r "$subdir" ) & done
      ```

      or by using absolute paths; e.g., `subdir="$PWD/dir.$i"`.