# Alias problems with inline job control

Tags: alias, job-control

I am having a problem with the following:

**Alias:**

```
alias gks='gitk --all &; clear; git status'
```

When I try it I see -

**Console Resp:**

```
$ gks
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

It appears to be the job control ('&') for the *gitk* command, is it possible to integrate this job control into an alias?

Comment: `&` on its own terminates the first command. See related [Use & (ampersand) in single line bash loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91684/use-ampersand-in-single-line-bash-loop)

Comment: thank you steeldriver!! such simplicity, just drop the semicolon after the &

Comment: Yep! This is what steeldriver shares above, working now