# Why does & work instead of &; for forks in 1 line bash loop

Tags: bash, syntax

If you write a 1 line shell script that forks a process, like the following:
`for i in {1..1000};do ./binary & done`

It runs, you don't need a semicolon, and if you try to use a semicolon it throws a syntax error.

In a normal loop, without forking, you need the semicolon for it to work in a 1 line script. Why does the fork operator change how this works?

Comment: Related: [Use & (ampersand) in single line bash loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91684/use-ampersand-in-single-line-bash-loop)

Comment: You end a command with either `;` or `&` depending on if you want the pipeline to run in the foreground or the background. A newline implicitly adds a semi-colon if the command can logically finish at that point.

Comment: The last sentence in the question body ends with `?`. Usually we use `.` to end a sentence. Why does the question mark change how this works? Why not `?.`? The same situation. You call `&` "fork operator" but it's a separator/terminator. So is `;`. You use one xor the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one run multiple programs in the background with single command?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/67006)